# JQuery tab show/hide error on nested tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am new to jquery, and I have tried to solve this problem, but I failed every time.

I have created this nested tab with bootstrap tab and custom JQuery tab section on my new website. But On the main tab I have added class `.active` to the second tab. But custom tab always loads the details from first tab. but after clicking on that tab, it loads the actual content.

parent tab is made by bootstrap tab, and the child tabs are custom.

to check the problem go to the "OUR AWESOME RENTAL FLEET CARS" section of the below url.

[HERE IS THE URL](http://gsdesilva.web2tips.com/)

JQUERY CODE I USED FOR SHOW CUSTOM TABS :

```
  $("#tab1 .car-details").hide();
  $("#tab1 .car-details:first").show();
  $("#tab1 ul.custom-tabs li").click(function() {
     $("#tab1 .car-details").hide();
     var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
     $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn();     

     $("#tab1 ul.custom-tabs li").removeClass("active-cst");
     $(this).addClass("active-cst");
  });



  $("#tab2 .car-details").hide();
  $("#tab2 .car-details:first").show();
  $("#tab2 ul.custom-tabs li").click(function() {
     $("#tab12 .car-details").hide();
     var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
     $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn();     

     $("#tab2 ul.custom-tabs li").removeClass("active-cst");
     $(this).addClass("active-cst");
   });


  $("#tab3 .car-details").hide();
  $("#tab3 .car-details:first").show();
  $("#tab3 ul.custom-tabs li").click(function() {
      $("#tab3 .car-details").hide();
     var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
     $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn();     

     $("#tab3 ul.custom-tabs li").removeClass("active-cst");
     $(this).addClass("active-cst");
 });


 $("#tab4 .car-details").hide();
 $("#tab4 .car-details:first").show();
 $("#tab4 ul.custom-tabs li").click(function() {
    $("#tab4 .car-details").hide();
    var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
    $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn();      

    $("#tab4 ul.custom-tabs li").removeClass("active-cst");
    $(this).addClass("active-cst");
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is not in your custom script, it is no you markup.

```
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs main-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">ECONOMIC CARS</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">PREMIUM CARS</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">LUXURY CARS</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">SUVs</a></li>
              </ul>
```

On above markup you have used `.active` class for first nav, but on the tabs you have, you have activate the second tab.

Just cut/paste the `active` class from first nav to second nav.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tab2 .car-details").hide();
$("#tab2 .car-details:first").hide();
$("#tab2 ul.custom-tabs li").click(function() {
      $("#tab12 .car-details").hide();
      var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
      $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn();        

      $("#tab2 ul.custom-tabs li").removeClass("active-cst");
});
```

`#tab12` Doesn't Exist Shoudn't it be `#tab2`

your `custom.js` file Line `Line 203.